# Turnstile followed by 'nothing'

Tags: logic, notation

In the literature, I came across the statement "A, ¬A ⊢." I'm uncertain about its meaning. Could this mean that any conclusion can be derived from having both A and its negation, ¬A, as premises?

Comment: Curious as to what literature? Also was anything there after the turnstyle, say a new var like B?

Comment: this is an equivalent way of writing $A, \neg A\vdash \bot$.

Comment: It is standard practice to write $P_1, \ldots, P_m \vdash Q_1, \ldots, Q_n$ to mean that the conjunction of the $P_i$ implies the disjunction of the $Q_j$. Along with the standard convention that an empty disjunction is $\bot$, this gives you the standard reading of $A, \lnot A \vdash$. Likewise it gives you the standard reading of $\vdash \lnot (A \land \lnot A)$.